# How to not let any mouse/cursor to enter the window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question,how to doesn't allow any mouse/cursor to  enter to window in wpf c# .I already try IsHitTestVisible =false and cursors.ovveride=none but the cursor still can enter and show up as arrow cursor. I want any mouse /cursor completely doesn't allow to enter the window when it in full screen. Thank you

Comment: Just the client rectangle?  Or do you want to make the system menu and minimize, close buttons inaccessible also?

Comment: try setting the backgroundcolor to transparent as well. i've had a bug once involving a similar scenario

Comment: @GarryVass- my window is maximized, Topmost="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None"

Comment: "can't enter" ? or "goes invisible" ?  "Can't enter" would likely require force-moving the mouse off the desired location...  I'm not sure those accessibility API's will be available in WPF.

Comment: @user3178993, have you looked in to the 'computer based training API'?  CBT apps have to take control of the mouse, keyboard, and other devices.  Also the screen saver gets disabled during a CBT app.  Maybe that's the pattern you are after?

Comment: @GarryVass- do you have any example for that?

Comment: @AndreasMüller- thanks! i already try but it doesnt work.

Comment: @ebyrob- goes invisible

Comment: @user3178993, I have no indicative code on CBT applications.  I can post an answer with some explanatory text and an onward link if that's of any use...  I can't tell if it's valuable at the moment...

Comment: I fail to see the purpose of preventing the cursor to get in your window area when that said window is in full screen. Where is the mouse supposed to go ?

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet- i have 2 screen,i just want to prevent the cursor enter in 1 screen with full screen window and the cursor should be in the other screen only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but this is a crude example that moves the mouse outside of the form whenever it enters:

```
    private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(this.Location.X - 1, this.Location.Y - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Cursor="None">
```

In Code (In the window's constructor):

```
 this.Cursor = Cursors.None;
```

Comment: This will set the cursor to be invisible, but fails when one of the controls adds a scroll viewer.  You can also access menu items with Cursor="None"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the cursor (and not preventing it to enter your window area), you can call [ShowCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the approriate parameter on MouseEnter and MouseLeave events of your window.